# Exception while parsing proto messages embedded in a json file

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

my json file looks like this:

```
[
{
"Timestamp": "2023-06-06T14:09:29.35+00:00",
"Topic": "probe_data_topic_v2",
"Partition": 0,
"Offset": 16427,
"SchemaId": null,
"SchemaType": null,
"Headers": {
"probe_uuid_header": "65e4939f-14bf-44bf-a799-bc99bcbbe20b"
},
"Message": "\\u001a�\\u0006\\n�\\u0001\\b\\n\\u0010�+\\u0018�ݩ��1*�\\u0001\\u001au\\n%\\n\\u0014Average ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-20.78 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Minimum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-21.72 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Maximum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-19.76 LKFS2\\f\\b\\u0002\\u0012\\b-22 LKFSB\\0H\\u000bP�\\u000bX�\\u0003b\\u0002\\bwpǦ\\rxɦ\\r�\\u0001\\00\\08\\u0001@\\u0001X�ک��1j\\u0007\\b�ݩ��1p��\\u0010\\n�\\u0001\\b\\n\\u0010�+\\u0018�ݩ��1*�\\u0001\\u001au\\n%\\n\\u0014Average ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-20.78 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Minimum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-21.72 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Maximum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-19.76 LKFS2\\f\\b\\u0002\\u0012\\b-22 LKFSB\\0H\\u000bP�\\u000bX�\\u0003b\\u0002\\bwpǦ\\rxɦ\\r�\\u0001\\00\\08\\u0002@\\u0001X�ک��1j\\u0007\\b�ݩ��1p��\\u0010\\n�\\u0001\\b\\n\\u0010�+\\u0018�ݩ��1*�\\u0001\\u001au\\n%\\n\\u0014Average ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-20.77 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Minimum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-21.70 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Maximum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-19.75 LKFS2\\f\\b\\u0002\\u0012\\b-22 LKFSB\\0H\\u000bP�\\u000bX�\\u0003b\\u0002\\bwpǦ\\rxɦ\\r�\\u0001\\00\\08\\u0003@\\u0001X�ک��1j\\u0007\\b�ݩ��1p��\\u0010\\n�\\u0001\\b\\n\\u0010�+\\u0018�ݩ��1*�\\u0001\\u001au\\n%\\n\\u0014Average ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-20.77 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Minimum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-21.70 LKFS\\n%\\n\\u0014Maximum ITU Loudness\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u000b-19.75 LKFS2\\f\\b\\u0002\\u0012\\b-22 LKFSB\\0H\\u000bP�\\u000bX�\\u0003b\\u0002\\bxpǦ\\rxɦ\\r�\\u0001\\00\\08\\u0004@\\u0001X�ک��1j\\u0007\\b�ݩ��1p��\\u0010 �����1"
},
]
```

The value of the message key is a proto message. I am trying to deserialize it using parseFrom() method. Code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("/export/home/users/ajay.kumar/WorkSpace/TestingMavenProject/Test/src/main/java/Testing/Test/new.json")) 
    {
        // Read JSON file
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray employeeList = (JSONArray) obj;
        JSONObject newjson = (JSONObject) employeeList.get(0);
        String datajson = newjson.get("Message").toString();
        byte[] bjson = datajson.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(newjson.get("Message").toString());
        try {
                ProbeDataWrapper probeDataWrapper = ProbeDataWrapper.parseFrom(bjson);
                System.out.println(probeDataWrapper);
        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

'''
But I get exception like:

```
Exception :- Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
```

I guess there is some issue in the way I am reading the message from json and passing it to parseFrom() function.
What am I doing wrong here. I am new to protobufs, so pardon my ignorance.